# cannot implement GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying simply to display an openGL surface when I click the screen using GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY mode

but the surface does not display when I click it , why ?

my Activity :

```
public class ViewManager extends Activity {
    private GLSurfaceView surfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        surfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        surfaceView.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
        surfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

        surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event!=null){
                    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        surfaceView.requestRender();
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        surfaceView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        surfaceView.onPause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have never actually added the surfaceView to the activity. So add this at the end of your activity's onCreate method should fix that.

```
setContentView(surfaceView);
```

Comment: but if I add the surfaceView to the activity it instantly appears . I want it to appear only when I call the requestRender command

Comment: Well just take what I just said and replace it with `surfaceView.requestRender();` instead.

Comment: @yanish Well then add it to the activity when you want it to appear? Having it not appear instantly is *not* the purpose of RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY.